# python内にある機能をterminalからbuilt-inした後、コード記入箇所でimportを試みても「No module named ""」となる原因について

Tags: python

■添付資料1　
①左上箇所　コード入力箇所
②右上箇所　Run
③下箇所　　terminal

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 行ったこと

③terminal上でtermcolorというpython内にある機能をインポート
①で添付コードを記入
②に"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termcolor'"と表示

学習しているサイト(Udemy)と同じ手順で進めたのですが、上記エラーが表示されています。
可能性として1、手順そのものが間違っている　2、利用しているアプリケーション(pycharm。 Anacondaと連携)の設定が間違っている
があり、後者かなと思っております。

添付資料2の通り動画教材の講師と同じことを実行しているため。
(有料動画のため画像のみ掲載)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

添付資料3としてpycharmの設定状況を貼り付けております。
どのような設定をすれば解消できそうかぜひご教授いただきたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: importできないのは、pyfigletというモジュールがインストールされていないからだと思われます。（インストールされていないので、"そんなモジュール無いよ"というエラーメッセージが出ている）

"pip install pyfiglet"というような、モジュールをインストールする操作をされましたか？

Comment: Terminal(Anaconda環境)では pyfiglet の import に成功していますので、おそらく、プロジェクトの configuration で Conda 環境との連携を選択しなかったのではないかと推察します。

Comment: @metropolis さん
ご回答ありがとうございます。
みなさまの解答を確認した後、動画を見返したのですが
moduleがインストールされていないことや、講師とコードが違うということはなさそうでした。

アナコンダの設定についてですが、どういう原因が考えられるかご教授いただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: @Fumu7 
ご教授いただきありがとうございます。
再度動画を見返したのですが、上記syntaxのコードを入力してもエラーとなっているようでした。
したがって、別に原因がありそうで、アナコンダ側との連携に問題がありそうな気がしております。

Comment: run/debug configuationsの中にある、Python interprePython interpreter の選択肢をpython3.8からProject Defaultに変更したところ、問題が解消しました。

選択していたものが、アナコンダと連携していなかったのかと思われます。
ご回答いただいた皆さまありがとうございました。